# NSFetchResultsController throws error during update two elements simultaneosly

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying two update elements in collection view. When I pass just one message it works nicely

```
func simulate() {
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
   FriendsController.createMessageWithText(text: "Here's a text message that was sent a few minutes ago...", friend: friend!, minutesAgo: 1, context: context)
  //second message  
    FriendsController.createMessageWithText(text: "Another message to give you hard time.", friend: friend!, minutesAgo: 1, context: context)
    do {
    try context.save()

    }
     catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

but when I do same steps except passing two messages it throws error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught
>   during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an
>   observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. 
>   Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of
>   items contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be
>   equal to the number of items contained in that section before the
>   update (6), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from
>   that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
>   with userInfo (null)

Maybe someone have any clue?

There are: NSFetchController and delegate function I implemented:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> NSFetchedResultsController<Message> in
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Message>(entityName: "Message")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"date",ascending: true)]
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friend.name = %@", (self.friend?.name!)!)
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()


   func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    if type == .insert {
        collectionView?.insertItems(at: [newIndexPath!])
        collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: newIndexPath!, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert(or delete, reload) more than one cell, than you need to make it in `performBatchUpdates` method of UICollectionView instance. You need to call it in `func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)`.

Look at this example: https://github.com/NoFearJoe/Timmee/blob/master/Timmee/Timmee/Sources/Core%20layer/Database/StorageObservable.swift

or:
https://gist.github.com/tempire/debbabb2cccafa90320e